# How to create "PersistentVolumeClaim" in Kubernetes on "Docker for windows"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

In the **"Juju"** installation of kubernetes in Vsphere, we create pvc as follows,

```
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: db-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: fast
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

with the **storageClassName** as **"fast"**. What it the storage class we need to create a "PersistentVolumeClaim" in "Docker for windows" installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A **StorageClass** provides a way for administrators to describe the
>   “classes” of storage they offer. Different classes might map to
>   quality-of-service levels, or to backup policies, or to arbitrary
>   policies determined by the cluster administrators. Kubernetes itself
>   is unopinionated about what classes represent. This concept is
>   sometimes called “profiles” in other storage systems.

You can create several StorageClasses that fit your needs referring to vSphere examples in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#vsphere):

> ### vSphere
>
> Create a StorageClass with a user specified disk format.
>
> ```
> kind: StorageClass
> apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
> metadata:
>   name: fast
> provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
> parameters:
>   diskformat: zeroedthick
> ```
>
> **diskformat**: thin, zeroedthick and eagerzeroedthick. Default: "thin".
>
> Create a StorageClass with a disk format on a user specified
>   datastore.
>
> ```
> kind: StorageClass
> apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
> metadata:
>   name: fast
> provisioner: kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume
> parameters:
>     diskformat: zeroedthick
>     datastore: VSANDatastore
> ```
>
> **datastore**: The user can also specify the datastore in the StorageClass. The volume will be created on the datastore specified in
>   the storage class, which in this case is VSANDatastore. This field is
>   optional. If the datastore is not specified, then the volume will be
>   created on the datastore specified in the vSphere config file used to
>   initialize the vSphere Cloud Provider.
>
> #### Storage Policy Management inside kubernetes
>
> Using existing vCenter SPBM policy
>
> One of the most important features of vSphere for Storage Management
>   is policy based Management. Storage Policy Based Management (SPBM) is
>   a storage policy framework that provides a single unified control
>   plane across a broad range of data services and storage solutions.
>   SPBM enables vSphere administrators to overcome upfront storage
>   provisioning challenges, such as capacity planning, differentiated
>   service levels and managing capacity headroom.
>
> The SPBM policies can be specified in the StorageClass using the
>   storagePolicyName parameter.
>
> #### Virtual SAN policy support inside Kubernetes
>
> Vsphere Infrastructure (VI) Admins will have the ability to specify
>   custom Virtual SAN Storage Capabilities during dynamic volume
>   provisioning. You can now define storage requirements, such as
>   performance and availability, in the form of storage capabilities
>   during dynamic volume provisioning. The storage capability
>   requirements are converted into a Virtual SAN policy which are then
>   pushed down to the Virtual SAN layer when a persistent volume (virtual
>   disk) is being created. The virtual disk is distributed across the
>   Virtual SAN datastore to meet the requirements.
>
> You can see Storage Policy Based Management for dynamic provisioning
>   of volumes for more details on how to use storage policies for
>   persistent volumes management.
>
> There are few vSphere [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/vsphere) which you try out for persistent
>   volume management inside Kubernetes for vSphere.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I found the answer,

`kubectl get storageclass` gives output as follows,

```
NAME                 PROVISIONER          AGE
hostpath (default)   docker.io/hostpath   22h
```

then, we can use 'hostpath' as the value for 'storageClassName'